# New variable based on several conditions (Stata)

Tags: stata

I have three variables structured as below:

```
pre_covid   change  post_covid
employed    Same         .
Housewif    Same         .
Business    diff      out of LF
employed    diff      unemployed
employed    Same         .
Housewif    Same         .
```

However, rather than missing (.) for those whose status has not changed since the recession started, I want to create a variable as follows post-recession_status

```
pre_covid   change  post_covid   post_recession_status
employed    Same         .             employed 
Housewif    Same         .             Housewif 
Business    diff      out of LF        out of LF
employed    diff      unemployed       unemployed
employed    Same         .             employed    
Housewif    Same         .             Housewif
```

The dataex for the pre and post covid categories are as follows:

```
 1 "employed", modify
 2 "Unemployed", modify
 3 "out of LF", modify
 4 "Housewife", modify
 5 "student", modify
```

The dataex for the change variable is:

```
Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input float change 
2
2
1
1
end
label values change change 
label def change 1 "Different", modify
label def change 2 "Same", modify
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite edits, your data example is incomplete and inconsistent in several minor details: `diff` or `different`, `Housewif` or `Housewife`, `Unemployed` or `unemployed`, `Business` not a defined value label.

Still, this shows a similar dataset as an example (which came out of editing, some extra code and then `dataex`) and then some token code.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input long(pre_covid post_covid change)
1 . 2
4 . 2
6 3 1
1 2 1
1 . 2
4 . 2
end
label values pre_covid whatever
label values post_covid whatever
label def whatever 1 "employed", modify
label def whatever 4 "housewife", modify
label def whatever 6 "business", modify
label def whatever 2 "unemployed", modify
label def whatever 3 "out of LF", modify
label values change change
label def change 1 "different", modify
label def change 2 "same", modify

gen wanted = cond(change == 2, pre_covid, post_covid)
label val wanted whatever

list, sep(0)

     +-------------------------------------------------+
     | pre_covid   post_covid      change       wanted |
     |-------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  employed            .        same     employed |
  2. | housewife            .        same    housewife |
  3. |  business    out of LF   different    out of LF |
  4. |  employed   unemployed   different   unemployed |
  5. |  employed            .        same     employed |
  6. | housewife            .        same    housewife |
     +-------------------------------------------------+
```